# Safe way to authentication users with REST

Tags: users, 8

I can authentication and login user with below code in Jquery

```
$.ajax({
    url : "http://domain.com/user/login",
    type : 'post',
    data : 'form_id=user_login_form&name=' + encodeURIComponent("user") + '&pass=' + encodeURIComponent("password"),
    dataType : 'json',
    error : function(data) {
            //error code
    },
    success : function(data) {
      console.log(data);
        //success code
    }
});
```

But is seems this is not safe mode, and I think maybe someone can attack  bruteforce to find users password.**I want to know is this method safe(I don't think so) and what is solution for make this safe against brute-force login attack.**

**This Ajax request don't return any Json output**,It seems try to login and if authorized  then get `/user/uid`

[image]

**Note** "[User login REST format](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185494/user-login-rest-format)" is similar, but it's not duplicate, and it doesn't have an accepted answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User login REST format](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185494/user-login-rest-format)

Comment: @mradcliffe no, it is similar but it's not duplicate, also it has not accepted answer.

Comment: `I want to know is this method safe(I don't think so)` If this wasn't safe, why would Drupal Core allow it?

Comment: As an alternative, you could use [Oauth](https://www.drupal.org/project/oauth) module. Good read: https://www.drupalwatchdog.com/volume-4/issue-2/protecting-your-drupal-8-resources

Comment: @NoSssweat maybe  I should use it integrate with Authentication method, CSRF_token , Oauth, Cookie .... . I didn't much experience with REST Login /authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you're a header, should be like this:

[image]

[image]

```
{ 
    "_links": {
        "type": { 
            "href": "https://yoursite.com/rest/type/node/article"
    }
  },
  "title": [{"value": "test title"}],
  "body": [{"value": "test body"}]
}
```

Comment: still not working. I try both with and without basic authentication.

Comment: which one is correct I focus on it? try with or without Basic Authentication in  Authentication Tab?

Comment: is my param name is correct?  "name" "pass" and "form_id" ?

Comment: @zhilevan In Body select `raw` as in my 2nd pic

Comment: it's Ok for getting node content, I want authorized them with user/pass.

Comment: would you please try to authorized and login  , with user resource ?

Comment: did you checkmark Basic Authentication in your REST module configuration settings? I gtg, I'll help you more tomorrow, if you need.

Comment: yes, and also type valid user pass  in Basic Authentication section.

Comment: use `Content-type: application/hal+json` as header (see pic 1) for POST use `http://yourwebsite.com/entity/node` (see pic 2, up the very top, grey box, beside POST) **not** /user/login

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42366/discussion-between-zhilevan-and-no-sssweat).

Comment: I am in drupal 8, I try GET ` /node/3 ` work correctly but when enable  Basic Authentication it return access is denid. **in node REST resource**
GET
authentication: basic_auth, cookie
formats: json.
basic_auth is set up.

Comment: Thanks for you attention, is seems the problem because of postman, ( it worked correctly with Curl and jquery ajax ).