# User login REST POST returns HTML format

Tags: 8

I want to login to drupal through JSON, 
I read [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185494/user-login-rest-format) issue, but non of the proposed solutions helped me do that using Postman on `drupal 8.2.5`.
specially when I send this specification :

```
POST: http://example.com/user/login?_format=json
Content-type: application/json
Data: { "name": "admin", "pass": "myPassword" }
```

Response is: 200 OK,

But the result is in HTML foramt and just shows the login page of drupal website!

Comment: This question is solved here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185494/user-login-rest-format

Comment: I tested all of proposed answers of that issue, but non of them works correctly.

Comment: I think using Drupal 8.3-dev will solve your issue. There are a tremendous deal of fixes concerning REST in the new release. It's also possible to register anonymous users with REST for example in that version.

Comment: I used Drupal 8.3-dev, but the problem not solved and it returns the same result.