# {500 service unavailable (with message)} error when trying to register a user with API

Tags: 8

I want to register a user on drupal site through REST, 
I read [this](https://fonsvandamme.be/blog/how-create-user-rest-drupal-8) article, and implemented the instructtins exactly the same using Postman on `drupal 8.3`.

specially when I send this specification :

```
POST: http://example.com/user/register
Content-type: application/json
Data: { "name": [
  {
    "value": "test"
  }
],
"mail": [
  {
    "value": "aa@bb.com"
  }
],
"pass": [
  {
    "value": "test"
  }
]  }
```

Response is: 500 service unavailable (with message)

What should I do to solve the problem?

Comment: Check your Drupal log - it should show an error. What is the error?

Comment: error: InvalidArgumentException: Field 0 is unknown. in Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase->getTranslatedField() (line 506 of D:\wamp95\www\drupal83\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a stab in the dark here.

It seems that you have extra square brackets. I think this is why your error message refers to field 0 -- you're sending it an array. Try it exactly as the article displays, with no square brackets?

For example: 
    "pass": {
        "value": "test"
      }

Good luck.

### Update

To enable setting a password, you need to change a setting which is default in the install.

Go to admin/config/people/accounts (Configuration > People > Account Settings) and **uncheck**  "Require email verification when a visitor creates an account":

[image: Correct settings]

Granted you are allowing POST to Anonymous users as described in the article above, you should be good to go and get a response such as the following in PostMan:

```
{
  "uid": [
    {
      "value": "5"
    }
  ],
  "uuid": [
    {
      "value": "70738718-d4e9-455e-a1f6-cf95df613507"
    }
  ],
  "langcode": [
    {
      "value": "en"
    }
  ],
  "name": [
    {
      "value": "ac@bb.com"
    }
  ],
  "created": [
    {
      "value": 1487319576
    }
  ],
  "changed": [
    {
      "value": 1487319576
    }
  ],
  "default_langcode": [
    {
      "value": true
    }
  ],
  "user_picture": []
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I deleted the square brackets, now it returns : {422 Unprocessable Entity} error!

Comment: and log report is: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnprocessableEntityHttpException: A Password cannot be specified. It will be generated on login. in Drupal\user\Plugin\rest\resource\UserRegistrationResource->ensureAccountCanRegister() (line 164 of D:\wamp95\www\drupal83\core\modules\user\src\Plugin\rest\resource\UserRegistrationResource.php).

Comment: I'm running into the same error as you now. It goes away if I remove the pass parameter, but I think the point is that you wanted to generate a user with a password?

Comment: Of course,  user needs password. I think it's a core issue,  where should I propose it to be solved?

Comment: Updated my answer. If you want to ASSIGN the user a password, you must change your Account Settings Configuration. Otherwise, the user will be sent an email and they will set their own password.

Comment: thanks Christopher Borchert, could you help me on this issue too: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/226492/user-login-rest-post-returns-html-format