# Web service APIs returns HTML content instead of JSON response

Tags: symfony-services

I have used Drupal 7 before and the web services were working perfectly fine. I recently started working on Drupal 8 (8.8 to be precise), and the login service is not working properly. When I do not give the username or the password it should ideally give a message that username/password must be entered. But I am not getting any response here.

It's just returning HTML content. I have been searching lot of posts on this and nothing seems to work for me. I am testing the same in Postman. Below is the screenshot of the same.
[image: Postman screenshot with login service]

I have gone through the below links before posting here..

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31230351/drupal-8-restful-webservices-only-delivering-html

[User login REST POST returns HTML format](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/226492/user-login-rest-post-returns-html-format?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[User login REST format](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185494/user-login-rest-format)

Nothing seems to work for me. Kindly suggest. Need your help. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

For the postman section of your issue: /user/login?_format=json is a POST request (not get as in your screenshot) and the body should be JSON not x-www-form.