# Doing a post to create a node using Drupal services endpoint with Postman app

Tags: 7, services

I got my endpoint setup and I'm able to to do a get request to return a bunch of nodes. But I'm having issues doing a POST to create a new node.

I see that I would first need to do a user login post as seen in other tutorials. I tried doing that with the following settings in postman, but I'm getting a blank response. What could I be doing wrong? I've enable user resources as seen below also.

[image]

[image]

Comment: i'm posting my username and password. I'm expecting a session id response so I can use this ID to add to my 2nd POST header in order to create my node.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User login REST format](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185494/user-login-rest-format)

Comment: Maybe a duplicate, but there is a distinct way of doing so with Drupal 7 Services that this might be its own distinct answer if there isn't a Drupal 7 Services question/answer out there already. That said, I don't think this question has the relevant and specific information about the Services module configuration (despite the images) to answer appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that  petition you are calling the path user.login, but in services is user/login, with a slash.

Also, maybe you are not preceding the path with the base name of your api (normally is /api). So the url should be /api/user/login. You can see the path in 'Edit' tab, in 'Path to endpoint' field.
[image]

I recommend you the module [services tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_tools) which gives you a page  where you can see the urls of the endpoints. This module contains a submodule called services_definitions, enable it to have this page available.[image: Definitions tab]

[image: Example user login definition]

Comment: Thanks! that works, but why is my output html, shouldn't it be json format with the session id? http://prntscr.com/grvtqw

Comment: In services, api endpoint urls must have a prefix. For example, instead of /user/login it must be /api/user/login. You need add that prefix to the URL. You can see what prefix you must use in your configuration ( see the first screenshot of ky answer, that is the Page, and te field 'path to endpoint' it's the prefix.

Comment: If you're getting HTML, chances are a contrib module is hooking into the login process and interferring with the Services module. Here's a perfect example of a contrib module that unkowingly does just that: https://www.drupal.org/node/2167987

Comment: Sorry if I explained uncorrectly. In the screenshot's request is just calling the user/login page from Drupal which is user login form, is not calling the api endpoint.  See my previous response to know how to make the request to the correct endpoint.