# Creating an API via module routing files that includes csrf verification headers

Tags: 8, routes

I am working on migrating a custom API from D7 to D8 and am doing so by using module routing. I have a routing.yml file that looks like so:

```
ytp_user.api.login:
  path: "/api/v1/user/login"
  defaults:
    _title: "User API Login"
    _controller: '\Drupal\ytp_user\Controller\UserAPIController::login'
  methods: [POST]
  requirements:
    _csrf_request_header_token: "TRUE"
ytp_user.api.get_current_user:
  path: "/api/v2/user/me"
  defaults:
    _title: "User API Get Current User"
    _controller: '\Drupal\ytp_user\Controller\UserAPIController::getCurrentUser'
  methods: [GET]
  requirements:
    _custom_access: '\Drupal\ytp_user\Controller\UserAPIController::authorize'
```

In the first route, I am trying to validate a csrf token provided in the headers, via the requirement `_csrf_request_header_token: "TRUE"`, however, this does absolutely nothing. It doesn't validate or even check that the header exists as the [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/routing-system/structure-of-routes) suggests it should.

I've tried replacing this with `_csrf_token: 'TRUE'` which at least checks that the token exists in the query, but I can't get a valid token!!! If I grab a token from `/session/token` and then pass it along in the query as `?token=<token-from-session/token>` then I just get an error saying the CSRF token is invalid.

Am I missing another step or is the documentation just straight up incorrect? I have been searching for hours and everything suggests that what I have should work, so why is the CSRF token not being validated properly?

Comment: I've not used `_csrf_request_header_token` but I believe it's entirely separate from `_csrf_token`. The latter is the vanilla way of requiring a CSRF token to a route (eg. Devel uses it on the _Clear cache_ route), and it's supplied as a query parameter: see https://www.drupal.org/node/3048359. IIUC the header token was extracted from the REST module, uses the token from the `/session/token` endpoint and is for remote API use. Are you issuing a post/patch/put? Have you authenticated?

Comment: I read something recently that mentioned anon users don't have real sessions, that sessions are reinitialized for each request. To Andy's point, I wonder if you need to authenticate before these tokens can work.

Comment: Yeah, that’s exactly what the documentation says, but it’s not working as suggested. When using _csrf_token it checks for the token, but says it’s invalid when the token is from /session/token. When using _csrf_request_header_token, it doesn’t check the header at all. I’m issuing a post call, and I’m trying to authenticate, thats what I’m trying to get the csrf token for, to login a user. Is /session/token suppose to create cookie headers or something? I’m not sure what to connect, the documentation is absolute garbage.

Comment: That doesn’t make sense, wouldn’t you want to verify CSRF before you authenticate a user?

Comment: It doesn't look like it? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/221045/48114 (I really don't have any first hand experience with this though.)

Comment: Instead of controllers, you might want to use the REST API and create `@RestResource` plugins. CSRF authentication then comes from the `cookies` auth provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement `_csrf_request_header_token: "TRUE"` works only if user is connected because [CsrfRequestHeaderAccessCheck](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Access%21CsrfRequestHeaderAccessCheck.php/class/CsrfRequestHeaderAccessCheck/8.9.x) use session informations.
If you look at [CsrfRequestHeaderAccessCheck](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Access%21CsrfRequestHeaderAccessCheck.php/class/CsrfRequestHeaderAccessCheck/8.9.x) in the `access` method there is:

```
 if ($account
      ->isAuthenticated() && $this->sessionConfiguration
      ->hasSession($request)) {
```

To check if the user is connected and it there is a session identifier in the request if it's not it will go directly to:

```
// Let other access checkers decide if the request is legit.
    return AccessResult::allowed()->setCacheMaxAge(0);
```

so it will not check if `X-CSRF-Token` is in the headers or not even if you set the route requirement `_csrf_request_header_token: "TRUE"`.
**Code**
**MODULE.routing.yml**
MODULE.login:

```
  path: "/api/v1/user/login"
  defaults:
    _title: "User API Login"
    _controller: '\Drupal\MODULE\Controller\UserAPIController::login'
  methods: 'POST'
  requirements:
    _csrf_request_header_token: 'TRUE'
```

**UserAPIController.php**

```
class UserAPIController extends ControllerBase {
  
  public function login(Request $request) {
    $response['data'] = 'Some test data to return';
    $response['method'] = 'POST';

    return new JsonResponse( $response );
  }

}
```

**Test**

1. With Connected user
   [image]
2. with anonymous user
   [image]