# user login by php code

Tags: 8

i have an app that sends username and password to a php script. This script checks that a user exists on Drupal 8 with username and password entered but does not log the user. I need the user to log in. Can someone help me? thanks
Follows script code

```
use Drupal\user\UserAuthInterface;
use Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
// Boot Drupal.
$autoloader = require __DIR__ . '/autoload.php';

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$kernel = DrupalKernel::createFromRequest($request, $autoloader, 'prod', FALSE);
$kernel->boot();
// Recupero Nome utente e password
$nome_ut = $_POST['nome'];
$pass_ut = $_POST['pwd'];
// effettuo il controllo
$user_auth = \Drupal::service('user.auth');
$user_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user');

$accounts = $user_storage->loadByProperties(['name' => $nome_ut, 'status' => 1]);
$account = reset($accounts);

if ($account) {
    if ($user_auth->authenticate($nome_ut, $pass_ut))
       {
    // The credentials are correct.
       $id = $user_auth->authenticate($nome_ut, $pass_ut);
       print ("Accesso riuscito!");
           // Force session start if we don't already have a session.
               $session = \Drupal::service('session');
               if (!$session->isStarted()) {
               $session->migrate();
           }
           if (\Drupal::currentUser()->isAuthenticated()) {
               // This user is logged in.
               print ("Utente Loggato");
           } else {
               // This user is not logged in.
               print ("Utente non Loggato");
           }
           
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a rest endpoint? Because this is already handled by drupal core. See for example [this](https://www.drupal.org/docs/core-modules-and-themes/core-modules/jsonapi-module/what-jsonapi-doesnt-do#s-user-login) or [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/252484/74024)

Otherwise I think you're just missing `user_login_finalize` after your check if the user is logged in.

```
user_login_finalize($user);
//Eventually redirect the user somewhere
$user_destination = \Drupal::destination()->get();
$response = new RedirectResponse($user_destination);
$response->send();
```

Comment: Thanks Giuseppe.... now I try

Comment: But $user is???  I'll take it from the ID?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't link the full API but they're easily accessible: [user_login_finalize](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_login_finalize/8.9.x) takes an `UserInterface` object as argument... so you can use the `$account` you've loaded before in your example.